# Identifier refers to a private member of the component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

*.html*

```
  <offline-picks *ngFor="let pick of pickData" [data]="pick"></offline-picks>
```

*.ts*

```
export class OfflineArticlesPage {
  private pickData: picksModel[] = [];
  constructor(private localCacheService: LocalCacheServiceProvider) {
  }
}
```

When I used the `private member` as shown above it shows below error.I'm using [**Angular Language Service**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) extension on `VS code` editor.

> [Angular] Identifier 'pickData' refers to a private member of the
>   component

Hope using `private members` inside the component is good programming practice no? But as a solution for above issue was given as [**below comment on the extension's repo**](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/95).

> The language service will emit these errors because they will be
>   errors during AOT. Eventually, you will need to resolve these.
>
> We have plans to support access to private and protected members in
>   AOT but that will not land until at least 6.0 (spring of next year).

So can you tell me what will be the best way to declare members on the components?

**Update:**

I use `ionic cordova run android --prod --device` CLI command with latest Ionic `"ionic-angular": "3.5.3",`.But it works nicely on my Android device.That means it is working fine with the `AOT` too no? Then why this error (or warning actually)?

Comment: The warning is because `private` properties are only used within the component they're defined. If you want to use a property in the view (and thus, outside of that component), you need to declare it as public. So using `private` properties in the views is not a good practice at all.

Comment: Actually, this is a problem with `AoT`.You can see a great discussion about this on the below answer's link.It was huge discussion and great one too @sebaferreras

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They have to be `public` in order for `AoT` to work.

See here for a bit more details:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11978

Comment: Please see the `Update:` on my post too.Your thoughts about it?

Comment: I don't know what's Ionic doing (if it's doing AoT or JiT but if it works then it means it's JiT since it shouldn't work on AoT)

Comment: I have learned a lot about this issue using above link.Thank you so much :)

Comment: Not a problem :)